# How can I call on a parent method from outside the class?

Tags: php, inheritance, casting

Take the following example:

```
class A implements Serializable {
    serialize() {}
}
class B extends A {
    serialize() {}
}
```

Class A is a persistant but minimal class used on every page. class B is temporary admin only (used on a settings screen) class which populates members by reading files.

I need to serialize the object and store in the database twice, once for regular pages, and the second (with a limited life) for the admin page.

```
$instance = new B(); // and populate
$data = serialize( $instance );
```

This will always call the over-ridden method. Is there any way I could cast `$instance` to type `A` so that I can call on `class A`'s serialize method?

Comment: What about sending a token instead of casting and check it from B's method to check wheather to be call A's method

Comment: @silentboy You can't send additional parameters along with serialize. Already tried.

Comment: Wrap this with another method.

Comment: The whole point of overriding a method is to prevent what you want to do. When the method is called from outside the class, the override version of the method is called. Of course you could create an entirely different method from within the child class that does nothing other than call the parent method you want to call via `parent::serialize();`

Comment: Have you got any answer?? I also need this 

Comment: @santosh, I added a new method to the derived class and made it call the parent. TBH I cannot remember exactly why I needed this feature. I think I was trying to immitate the polymorphic nature of C++ classes.

Comment: @Twifty it was in mind also, but problem is that whenever we edit anything like function name or no. Of parameters, we have to change it everywhere else it will not work... I am building multiple modules of application so this option is not well suited.... I am looking something like `$object->parent::functionName();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible by creating a closure, Looks following snippet for demonstration

```
<?php

interface Greeting
{
    public function hello();
}

class A implements Greeting
{
    public function hello()
    {
        echo "Say hello from A\n";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    public function hello()
    {
        echo "Say hello from B\n";
    }
}

$b = new B();

$closure = function() {
    return parent::hello();
};

$closure = $closure->bindTo($b, 'B');
$closure(); // Say hello from A
$b->hello(); // Say hello from B
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you cannot. The children redeclare the parent functionality of the method and completely override it. For this, static methods would be required.

Comment: Considering the class still maintains a vtable, I'd have thought there would be a some trickery to do this.